# What permissions are required to GET_TEMPLATE for Firebase Remote Config?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-admin-sdk, firebase-remote-config

I have a Firebase Cloud Function that invokes an Admin SDK service account to request the Remote Config template to compare changes to the previous version. I have this working in 2 other Firebase instances, but in this instance, I'm getting this error in the cloud function logs:

```
Function execution started
rejected token
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
error encountered:
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "[AUTHORIZATION_ERROR]: User does not have the following permission: GET_TEMPLATE",
Function execution took 139 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

I have tried adding these permissions to the service account:

- Cloud Functions Admin
- Editor
- Firebase Analytics Viewer
- Firebase Remote Config Admin
- Service Account Token Creator

I have also tried deploying this cloud function on 3 different service accounts and they all receive the same error.
Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by adding the required permissions (cloudconfig.configs.get, cloudconfig.configs.update, and firebaseanalytics.resources.googleAnalyticsReadAndAnalyze) to the 'App Engine default service account'. This was confusing because we had thought that the default Firebase Admin SDK 'firebase-adminsdk-*****@projectId.iam.gserviceaccount.com' would be the default service account used to access the Remote Config GET_TEMPLATE. I know for certain we also tried manually specifying this service account when initializing the app in the Cloud Function. We even tried changing the 'Runtime service account' in the [Cloud Function](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/) -> Edit -> 'Runtime, build, connections and security' settings to use the service account and that didn't work (which seems like that might be a bug). Only adding the correct permissions to the App Engine default service account seemed to work in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

The only Remote Config permissions are [`cloudconfig.configs.get` , `cloudconfig.configs.update`and `firebaseanalytics.resources.googleAnalyticsReadAndAnalyze`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions#remote_config)

[Firebase IAM Permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions) lists the roles required for each product.

Also, it is important to note that "To authenticate a service account and authorize it to access Firebase services, you must generate a private key file in JSON format". Steps on how to do it and the same error similar to yours can be found in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60162108/firebase-remote-config-rest-authorization-error)

Comment: Thank you very much for this information, Ricardo. As I mention in the post, I have added IAM permissions for Firebase Analytics Viewer and Firebase Remote Config Admin to the service account, so it has all the possible Remote Config permissions you listed. All three service accounts I tried using had JSON private keys for the cloud function deployment as well.

Comment: You are correct, and it seems  that the error happens quite a lot, and only adding the  "Firebase Analytics Viewer" should fix it as a workaround. You might have to start fresh with an entry as suggested [in git](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1015)

Answer (score 0):

my solution was adding the `Firebase Remote Config Admin` role to the XYZ-123@appspot.gserviceaccount.com. not great that this is buried...!